# Example for several (fastcgi/uwsgi/scgi/proxy_pass) Mojolicious apps in the same nginx virtual host?

Tags: perl, apache2, nginx, fastcgi, mojolicious

I have some Mojolicious-based apps which happily run under Apache2 with mod_cgi and mod_fastcgi.

The urls are for example:

```
   http://example.org/oneapp/path/info?foo=bar
   http://example.org/oneapp?foo=bar
   http://example.org/secondapp/path/info?foo=bar
   http://example.org/thirdapp/path/info?baz=heh
   #etc...
```

I had relative success configuring the apps as [subdomains](https://github.com/kberov/MYDLjE/commit/5fdb8af717544ff6b5baeea164a783b4c473696b) using proxy_pass
but I would like to keep the old urls(just switch from apache2 to nginx).
I would like to keep the same urls but run the apps using nginx.
What should my configuration look like and how should I run the apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you haven’t got an answer, I’ll give a correct, but entirely half-baked and code-free, solution. Check the [Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook) for [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) and [Plack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack) deployment. Mix this with [Plack::Builder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack::Builder) for deploying multiple applications on the same server. I’d go with [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Starman) as the server engine probably but that is up to you and your specific needs.

That’s basically it. Sorry I don’t have code for you but that should do exactly what you want once you get through each step; the docs are good and can be supplemented with blog posts from various Perl devs.

Comment: Well, thanks, this is good advise.
I will try and make a complete example which I will put in my project and then link it here so people can enjoy it. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

see also [the Mount Plugin](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/Mount) which allows you to add one mojolicious app within another